# Why does "echo" operate like "echo -e" in my bash?

Tags: bash, echo

I stumbled upon a weird problem with `echo` on `GNU bash, version 5.1.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-solaris2.11)`:

```bash
bash-5.1$ builtin echo -e 'a\tb'
a       b

bash-5.1$ builtin echo 'a\tb'
a       b

bash-5.1$ builtin echo +e 'a\tb'
+e a    b
```

While it won't affect my scripts because I mostly use `printf`, **how do you turn `echo -e` off in bash**?

Comment: What is the output of `type echo` ?

Comment: `type echo` => `echo is a shell builtin`

Comment: If you open a new tab of virtual terminal, it's the same?

Comment: That's from a direct SSH session, no mux

Comment: Maybe ask to `#bash@libera.irc`

Comment: " The xpg_echo shell option may be used to dynamically determine whether or not echo expands these escape characters by default." . So run `shopt`  and see if it's enabled.

Comment: @nos I just turned it off and I got the "expected" `a\tb`

Comment: Even tho the prompt says bash, are you sure you're not using a shell like `zsh` where `-e` is enabled by default?

Comment: @0stone0 nope, my prompt turned out like this after typing `bash`

Comment: @nos you can post `shopt -u xpg_echo` as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: xpg_echo is on by default on solaris since long before bash 5.1

Comment: @oguzismail That's indeed true. I didn't notice it with the bash 4.x of Solaris 11.3/11.4...

Comment: yeah. if I recall correctly it's the same on macos, aix, hp-ux, and z/os too. that's why printf is preferred

Comment: this should be on [unix.se]

Comment: this is one of the reasons people recommend using `printf` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `xpg_echo` shell option enabled.

List the options by running `shopt`

Disable it with `shopt -u xpg_echo`

To figure this out, read the echo section of `man builtins` (assuming that gives you the bash builtin commands, otherwise look at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)

The relevant part is

> The xpg_echo shell option may be used to dynamically determine whether
> or not echo expands these escape characters by default.

Comment: It's true that it is an old option (bash 3.2 have it), but it's my first time getting it turned on by default...

Comment: @Fravadona There might be a .bashrc/.bash_profile for your user or globally on that particular machine that turns it on

Answer (score 2):

Since there are many possible ways for the `xpg_echo` option to get turned on, the safest option when you want to ensure that `echo` will not interpret backslash escapes may be to always use the `-E` option.  However, code like

```
echo -E "$var"
```

still doesn't work in general because "$var" might expand to an `echo` option.  I find it best to use `echo` only for simple literal strings, if at all.  Also see the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).